# Java exception: the statement didn't return a resultset

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, websphere

My original environment is **SQL server 2005 + WebSphere v6.0(JDBC 3.0)**. When I run the program as below and it works well.

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
rs.next();
```

However, when I upgrade the environment to **SQL server 2005 + WebSphere v8.5(JDBC 4.0)**, I get the error message:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not
>   return a result set.

From this forum's information, it seems that I have multiple resultsets, so I try to change the program as follows and it works fine.

```
stmt.execute(sql);
stmt.getMoreResults();
stmt.getMoreResults();
ResultSet rs=stmt.getResultSet();
rs.next();
```

My questions is that is there any approach that I can keep my program unchanged and works well with `JDBC 4.0 driver(WAS v8.5)` or any combination like `SQL svr 2000 + WAS v8.5`, etc.

Please give me any pointer and your recommendation is valuable to me, thank you.

Ann

Comment: Please post the statement, that'd be useful for analysis.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to execute a query that either produces multiple resultsets or that does not produce a resultset (eg `UPDATE`, `INSERT` etc) using `executeQuery`. The [Javadoc for this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) explicitly says:

> Throws: SQLException - if a database access error occurs, this method is called on a closed Statement, the given SQL statement **produces anything other than a single ResultSet object**

You either need to use the `executeUpdate` method (if it is actually an update/insert/delete, or `execute` and then use the resulting `boolean` and that of [`getMoreResults()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults%28%29) to decide how to proceed.