# Migration from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: java, database, sql-server-2012

Below code is working fine while we are using SQL Server 2008 but when we migrate the SQL Server 2003 database to SQL Server 2012 it does not get any value in resultset and it terminated from below bolded line "rs = cst.executeQuery()".

```
 try {
                db = new DBHandle();
                con = db.getConnection();

                String strSP = "{call sys_MSBcheck_login(?,?,?,?)}";

                cst = con.prepareCall(strSP);


                cst.setString(1, strUserName);
                cst.setString(2, strPassword);
                cst.setString(3, strSession);
                cst.setInt(4, compId);
                **rs = cst.executeQuery();**
                logger.info("strUserName :"+strUserName + " strPassword :"+strPassword+ " strSession :"+strSession +" compId :"+compId );
                logger.info("sys_MSBcheck_login is called");
                String strStatus = null;
                int intLoginGroupID = 0;

                int intLDAPUser = 0;

                if (rs.next()) {
                    strStatus = rs.getString("result");
                    intLoginID = rs.getInt("login_id");
                    intPwdBit = rs.getInt("pwdbit");
                    intLoginGroupID = rs.getInt("login_group_id");
                    intpre_expired_state = rs.getInt("pre_expired_state");
                    strLoginStatus = rs.getString("LoginStatus");
                    intWarningDays = rs.getInt("WarningDays");
                    intLDAPUser = rs.getInt("LDAPUser");
                    intProvType = rs.getInt("provision_type");
                    if (intLDAPUser == 0) {
                        isLDAPUser = "no";
                    }
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.error("Exception in validate user" + e);
            }
```

It shows below error log

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
```

Comment: What does the database say in response to that?

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.

Comment: Where on earth you foud out SQL Server 2003. Please correct your question

Comment: Have you verified that the username exists and that the password is correct?  Do you know for certain that the username you gave did really get loaded into the database?

Comment: yes i have the username and corresponding password too.

Answer (score 0):

"The statement did not return a result set" might be caused by the SQL Server JDBC driver getting confused with row counts when your stored procedure performs any inserts or updates prior to the final select statement. To resolve this issue, you can add SET NOCOUNT ON; at the beginning of your stored procedure [see previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46231766/2067753).

Alternatively, perhaps use `execute()` method instead of `executeQuery()`.

The executeQuery() method should  be used with queries whose only result is a single ResultSet, and some JDBC drivers may just ignore and discard DDL and DML results in executeQuery() rather than throwing an exception [techcommunity.microsoft.com](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/sqlserverexception-the-statement-did-not-return-a-result-set/ba-p/383465). You can use the `execute()` method and  `getMoreResults()`  to execute complex queries [see previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14170821/2067753)